# What's a verb that means carefully crafting language to avoid future accusations of hypocrisy?

Tags: verbs, idioms

Examples:

- Any time that you're ____ing, you should probably reconsider your actions.
- To the astute, the ____ing was disgusting behavior - to the average person, it just sounded sensible.
- I couldn't reveal the whole story, so I just ____ed, hoping that nobody would listen, those who listened would forget, and those who didn't forget would seem whiny and stuck in the past.

Prophylactic double-speak[ing] doesn't get to the heart of the hypocrisy.

Advocating for the Devil seems too well-intentioned.

False im-moralizing just confusing.

Temporary/transient normalization is too buzz-wordy.

Comment: [hypocrisy](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hypocrisy) *The practice of claiming to have higher standards or more noble beliefs than is the case.* Simply claim to have no standards and espouse base beliefs so that you error in the other direction.  Carefully crafted language = "smoother hypocrisies of diplomacy".

Comment: "blowing smoke" could work.  The links from the freedictionary are hard to properly credit in an answer, but the definitions cited there (from other dictionaries) paint the idiom pretty well. http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/blow+smoke *to state something in a way that conceals the truth. (see also smoke and mirrors.) She is a master at blowing smoke. She belongs in government.*

Answer (score 4):

You could use [***equivocate***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/equivocate). From Merriam-Webster:

> 1 :  to use [equivocal](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/equivocal) language especially with intent to deceive
> 2 :  to avoid committing oneself in what one says

And equivocal:

> 1 a :  subject to two or more interpretations and usually used to mislead or confuse

This sounds very close to what you describe, with the equivocal language presumably being chosen carefully so one can't be pinned down, which would presumably protect against accusations of hypocrisy (among other possible accusations). However, it's not very common and is a fairly formal term. If you want a more casual synonym, [***hedge***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hedge) works well; again from M-W:

> *noun* 3 :  a calculatedly noncommittal or evasive statement
>
> *verb* 2 :  to evade the risk of commitment especially by leaving open a way of retreat

Again, this is very similar to your proposed definition. Note that both *equivocate* and *hedge* can sometimes be used neutrally or almost positively (sometimes this is the wisest course of action; I think *hedge* is slightly more neutral than *equivocate*, which is sometimes listed as a direct synonym of *lie*).

If you want a *really* pejorative term, which is also fairly colorful and quite informal, you could try *(use) [**weasel words**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/weasel%20words)*:

> Definition of weasel word
> :  a word used in order to evade or retreat from a direct or forthright statement or position

So, in increasing order of formality:

- Any time that you're **using weasel words**, you should probably
  reconsider your actions.
- To the astute, the **hedging** was
  disgusting behavior - to the average person, it just sounded
  sensible.
- I couldn't reveal the whole story, so I just
  **equivocated**, hoping that nobody would listen, those who listened would forget, and those who didn't forget would seem whiny and stuck
  in the past.

Comment: Equivocating connotes weakness in my mind... I was hoping to implicitly evoke disdain, not pity. In hindsight, my motives may be childish... I like weaseling quite a bit.

Comment: Also, *circumlocute* or *circumlocuting* (from *circumlocution*) might be something you want to look up.

Answer (score 1):

***To be economical with the truth*** - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economical_with_the_truth

> *Any time that you'**re being economical with the truth**, you should probably reconsider your actions*.
>
> *To the astute, **being economical with the truth** was disgusting behavior - to the average person, it just sounded sensible.*
>
> *I couldn't reveal the whole story, so I **was just economical with the truth**, hoping that nobody would listen, those who listened would forget, and those who didn't forget would seem whiny and stuck in the past*.

Comment: Very euphamistic.